# Java Enum unused field warning

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, warnings

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public enum Type {
    INFO("INFO"),
    WARN("WARN"),
    ERROR("ERROR"),
    FATAL("FATAL");

    private String value;

    private Type(String aValue) {
        value = aValue;
    }
};
```

[image]

I get warning about value being unused...

all I can think about is using @SupressWarnings for it but I'm new to enum so I'm just checking here if maybe I did something wrong... any thoughts?

Comment: The IDE isn't lying.  You set the variable, but you never use it or provide any way to retrieve it.

Comment: Know, that `Type.INFO.toString()` will give `"INFO"` and `Type.valueOf("WARN")` will give a `Type.WARN`. So value is not needed, the same as `toString()` or `getName()`.

Comment: @Joop, yeah I was just kind of figuring that out... thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It displays a warning, because the field value is never being read.

To simply skip this warning, just provide a getter for the field.

```
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: +1; but variable is still not used as long as the method is not used anywhere :-) So it might make sense to remove the variable as it won't provide any benefit...

Comment: @home As long as it's a public getter, and there's some sort of factory or access to the constructor from outside the class, the compiler won't flag it down.

Comment: @hexafraction: of course, but it's still not used... the compiler is just not aware of that fact

Comment: @home Not used within the project!=not used by other classes outside the class potentially loading this class.

Comment: @hexafraction: ok, let's say that as long there is no need for the getter, the variable is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I see why it is confusing, but **assignment** does not count as being used.  The variable actually has to be used in an expression before that occurs.  In this case, that means that `value` will either be used inside the class to perform some computation, or you write a getter.  In either case, the variable is now "used".

Answer (score 0):

It means you're *writing* to it, but never reading from it. Do you need it ? If not then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean unread, not unused? The VM is trying to tell you that you are setting a value but not doing anything with it - usually a bug. Definitely don't use @SuppressWarnings. Either fix the bug (use the value) or stop tracking the variable.

Answer (score 0):

IDE  is not complaining,It's just trying to help you to `remove` unused and unnecessary  `code`.

If you use the `value` somewhere,It removes that `warning`.

Since you declared   `private String value;`  and not using so, it's informing you,So that you will take necessary steps.